# Re-open submitted form

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm trying to determine if Cognito Forms would work for my use case. We manage small scientific datasets and require researchers to provide metadata for these datasets. The capabilities of Cognito Forms looks like it'll cover everything, except one particular about managing entries.

We'd like to be able to have somebody be able to re-edit a form that's already been submitted previously, maybe even 6 months to a year later. What I'd like to be able to do is "re-open" that submitted form and allow someone to be able to go in and make changes or additions.

I've read about save and resume, but what I'm really looking for is the ability to re-open a completed form for editing or additions by somebody, ideally by just sending them a link to the previously filled out form.

Is this something that is/will be/never will be supported by Cognito Forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are adding support for [sharing entries](https://trello.com/c/pbrbGrft) to [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) in the next week or so.  This will definitely accomplish your goals.  You will be able to send out links that allow editing of submitted entries or kick them back to incomplete to allow them to be "resubmitted".